# Is there a difference between is_int() and ctype_digit()?

Tags: php, function, numbers

Is one more preferred, or performs better over the other?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

[`is_int()`](http://php.net/is_int) returns true if the argument is an integer type, [`ctype_digit()`](http://www.php.net/ctype_digit) takes a string argument and returns true if all the characters in the string are digits.

**Example:**

```
┌──────────┬───────────┬────────────────┐
│          │  is_int:  │  ctype_digit:  │
├──────────┼───────────┼────────────────┤
│ 123      │  true     │  false         │
├──────────┼───────────┼────────────────┤
│ 12.3     │  false    │  false         │
├──────────┼───────────┼────────────────┤
│ "123"    │  false    │  true          │
├──────────┼───────────┼────────────────┤
│ "12.3"   │  false    │  false         │
├──────────┼───────────┼────────────────┤
│ "-1"     │  false    │  false         │
├──────────┼───────────┼────────────────┤
│ -1       │  true     │  false         │
└──────────┴───────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: Impressive answer!

Comment: One quirk not mentioned here: "If an int between -128 and 255 inclusive is provided, it is interpreted as the ASCII value of a single character (negative values have 256 added in order to allow characters in the Extended ASCII range). Any other integer is interpreted as a string containing the decimal digits of the integer." So `ctype_digit(123)` = false, but `ctype_digit(1234)` = true. To get more consistent behaviour, cast the input to string: `ctype_digit((string)$x)`.

Comment: As of PHP 8.1.0, ctype_digit will always interpret the argument as a string.

Answer (score 10):

There is also [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) which returns true if passed in value can be parsed as number.

[image]

If I try to compare performance of functions on **PHP 5.5.30** here are the results:

[image]

This is the code I used for benchmark

```
// print table cell and highlight if lowest value is used
function wr($time1, $time2, $time3, $i) {
    if($i == 1) $time = $time1;
    if($i == 2) $time = $time2;
    if($i == 3) $time = $time3;

    echo('<td>');
    if(min($time1, $time2, $time3) === $time) printf('<b>%.4f</b>', $time);
    else printf('%.4f', $time);
    echo('</td>');
}


$test_cases = array( 123, 12.3, '123', true);
$tests = 1000000;
$result = true;  // Used just to make sure cycles won't get optimized out
echo('<table>'.PHP_EOL);
echo('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><th>is_int</th><th>ctype_digit</th><th>is_numeric</th></tr>');
foreach($test_cases as $case) {
    echo('<tr><th>'.gettype($case).'</th>');

    $time = microtime(true);
    for($i = 0; $i < $tests; $i++) {
        $result |= is_int((int)rand());
    }
    $time1 = microtime(true)-$time;

    $time = microtime(true);
    for($i = 0; $i < $tests; $i++) {
        $result |= ctype_digit((int)rand());
    }
    $time2 = microtime(true)-$time;

    $time = microtime(true);
    for($i = 0; $i < $tests; $i++) {
        $result |= is_numeric((int)rand());
    }
    $time3 = microtime(true)-$time;

    wr($time1, $time2, $time3, 1);
    wr($time1, $time2, $time3, 2);
    wr($time1, $time2, $time3, 3);
    echo('</tr>'.PHP_EOL);
}

echo('</table>');

exit();
```

Answer (score 3):

The last thing you should be worrying about is how fast one of these is.  There is no way that checking a string for being an integer is going to be a bottleneck in your code.

Answer (score 3):

ctype **not** always *return false* on integer type.

```
foreach(range(-1000 , 1000)as $num){
    if(ctype_digit($num)){
        echo $num . ", ";
    }    
}
```

ctype_digit return true for the following integer type number.

-78,-77,-71,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,178,179,185,
256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270 to 1000

the base practice is to case every number to string e.q. strval($num) or (String) $num
in this case negative value (-78) will always return false.

is_int will return you true on int type value between -2147483647 to 2147483647.
any value exceed that number will return you false presuming it is running on 32bits system.
on 64bits it can go up to range of -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807

in term of performance personally very hard to say. ctype_digit maybe faster than is_int but if you have to cast every value to string performance is reduced overall.

Comment: ctype_digit is for use on string only

Comment: Those three characters in the upper character range (178, 179, 185) are interesting. Did older versions of PHP think there were digits in there, or does this happen with non-standard codepages?
[Aside: range() doesn't make an iterator, it makes an array: don't use it for looping, because it WILL bite you: it can cause segfaults with large integers.]

Answer (score 3):

Well it's very interesting :) Here is all story:

> **`is_numeric:`** — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string, No matter value is negative or Boolean or String or any type
>   of number, if value is purely number it will return **`'true'`** else **`'false'`**.
>
> **Remember: No Character Only Number any type :)**

---

> **`is_init`**— Find whether the type of a variable is integer, if value is purely integer then it will return 'true' else 'false'.
>
> **Remember: No Character, Double or Negative, Only Integer**

---

> **`in_integer`**— Alias of is_int()

---

> **`intval:`**— Get the integer value of a variable, it's take all kind of value and returns only Integer value, if values are negative then
>   returns '**`-Integer`**' value. No matter values are Integer, Float,
>   Negative or '**`NumberString`**' or '**`NumberStringCharacter`**'.
>   It's subtract the Integer values from string "**`If String Starts with
>   Number`**".
>
> - **NumberString** = A Number value in String Format
> - **NumberStringCharacter** = A String Start with Number
>
> **Remember: You will get Integer value from Number, Float, Negative or String which is starts with Number.**

---

> **`ctype_digit`**— Check for numeric character(s), If a Whole Number supplied in String Format you will get '**`true`**' else '**`false`**'. It will
>   work with only StringNumber, No Float, No Negative only Whole Number
>   as String.
>
> **Remember: Whole Number as String, No Negative Number, No Float Number, No Number Type, No Character, Only Number as String.**

**Birds Eye View:**

[image]

**Thanks to http://php.net/**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really care if the argument is a int type or a string with numbers, use is_numeric. It will return true for floats also, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Ctype_digit returns false if the range of integer is in negative range or between 0 and 47 or between 58 and 255. You can check ctype_digit's behavior by using the following snippet.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
var_dump(
    true === array_every(range(-1000, -1), 'ctype_digit_returns_false'),
    true === array_every(range(0, 47), 'ctype_digit_returns_false'),
    true === array_every(range(48, 57), 'ctype_digit_returns_true'),
    true === array_every(range(58, 255), 'ctype_digit_returns_false'),
    true === array_every(range(256, 1000), 'ctype_digit_returns_true')
);

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every
function array_every(array $array, $callable)
{
    $count = count($array);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i +=1) {

        if (!$callable($array[$i])) {

            return false;

        }

    }

    return true;
}

function ctype_digit_returns_true($v)
{
    return true === ctype_digit($v);
}

function ctype_digit_returns_false($v)
{
    return false === ctype_digit($v);
}
```